# Why do Daminion photo previews off the local drive take a long time to appear?

Tags: software

I have Daminion local, not server here with a catalog of about 20,000 photos, mostly JPG.

When I double-click on a thumbnail to see full-screen view, there's a significant delay now that I'd like to avoid.

Low-resolution image usually appears fast, but then it takes forever for it to become full-resolution.

That delay is not consistent, either. Sometimes 3 seconds, sometimes 15 seconds.

How do I make full-screen previews appear faster?

Comment: Whoops wrong window. Please ignore close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the factors that impact to the speed of displaying full-screen previews in Daminion:

- Images from remote locations (NAS, network folders) opens slower than local files
- When CMS is turned On
- TIFF and RAW files are opened slower than JPEGs
- 15 MP images are opened slower than 3-5 MP images
- Background processes might drastically impact to the image viewing: importing files or syncing tags with metadata.
- Free RAM and CPU

Please give us more info about your environment and the above factors.

Comment: You should also mention data topography on the harddrive - specifically the issue of fragmentation. But even fetching complete files from different locations is slower than streaming continuously. (I am assuming data is not stored on a SSD)

Comment: Thanks Marat. Turns out, currently running Catalog Import (I guess you can call it Background Process?) was slowing things down. If you stop catalog import, full-screen previews open fast as expected.